# Ideas. Mobile App with Scores

Tags: mobile-application

I need to create an app which allows users to score sections of a questionnaire. The score ranges from 1 - 10, speed would dictate that buttons would be the fastest way to do this and it is something we have done before when the scoring system ranged from 1 to 4. However would 10 buttons take up too much space, would the buttons would be too small to be accessible?

Here's a mock of ideas I'm considering:

[image: Mocks]

1. Access shows the slider, we're not 100% certain the framework we are using will support it. Possible issues are accurate score selection, slightly confusing numbers shown to the user.
2. Buttons, one of the quickest selections, something we've tried and tested in the past, instant visual of the score rating and how it fits with the users matrix. Pitfalls, makes the interface look busy (there will be 10 questions in all) fiddly for fat fingers.
3. Fire Precautions shows another method we've used in the past. The number is tapped, every tap increments it by 1. Pitfalls are that in previous apps the max score has been 5, with the max score here being 10 with 10 questions it could be a lot of taps. It's not immediately obvious what you're supposed to do to enter a score, we've looked at several icon designs to indicate that the numbers increments, if you tap past the number you want it is an entirely infuriating experience.

Here's another method I'm considering:

[image: Up/Down]

Can't see many pitfalls with this, can you?

Would appreciate your ideas and comments.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My concern is for your engagement. A score range of 10 is a lot and it could scare of users. Especially when there are a lot of items to be scored. Few weeks ago I was asked to fill in a questionnaire while waiting on the train. They asked me to rate the station on different aspects. The first five I filled in seriously. By the end (and there were only 15 questions) I was hardly reading the questions and just semi-randomly picking a score.

Reducing the range will work best for your engagement.

Examples:
**Shopify support rating**

[image]

Shopify has a great support and they almost always follow up on their customers that have questions, just to be sure. At the end of their emails they'll ask for a score. In the image you see just three options visually supported by emoticons. Choosing is easy and elaborating on your choice is optional.

**Tinder**

[image]

Tinder is a dating app that has grown popular because of the ease. It's a bit superficial, but it works! What makes this app work is the rating part. Just two choices. Yes or no. Easily done.

**Polar Polls**

[image]

[Polar](http://www.polarb.com) does this great too. Polls with too many options will give irregular results. The idea behind Polar is, why not cut the poll up into multiple little polls. Polar says engagement will go up way more with their multiple simple polls than with one bigger poll.

My advice for you: Give the user two or three options. Fun / neutral / boring if you want an overall score of a particular part of the questionnaire. Or break it up in multiple questions. What did you think of the questions? Simple / Too hard. Etc.

If you do have to go for a rating of 10, I would go for the buttons. Sure there are a lot of them but they still only require one click where the other two will require an average of 5 clicks and as for the slider, that one requires more concentration.

Comment: The scoring system, unfortunately, is not ours but the clients. I'm always happy to suggest things and will put a reduced scale as one of our proposals, but I suspect it is this way because the data will eventually be stored in a management system for dashboard display.